# Styling the background of an Element HTML

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I am trying something new, except when I try to create a background for my H1 element I have no way of making sure the background color borders fit to the top of the screen, left and right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css"
<body>
<title>Test Tab</title>
<div class="main">
    <h1>Website Heading</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>

.main {
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: #00ff00;
 background-position: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your CSS to this:

```
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.main {
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: #00ff00;
 background-position: 10px;
}

.main h1 {
  margin:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bxz0pf8/)

You need to make sure you set your body to have no padding or margins and also make sure your `h1` doesn't have any margin either. That way it will happily sit at the top of your page.

Comment: Thanks. However, my issue is that I can't quite get the background color to be bigger and match the margins, so the color touches the top of the webpage for example